# Video is jittery on iPad after playing

Tags: ios, ipad, video, html5-video

I've got an html5 video tag and I'm using video.js. On my desktop browsers, it works beautifully.
On the iPad however...

When I load the page on the iPad, everything looks great. When I touch the play button and the image is replaced with the player, it starts jittering back and forth. Even once it's done playing, it continues to jittery back and forth.

Here's a video of it happening...

http://youtu.be/4IaEBD0p2hw

Has anyone seen this happen before? Any ideas?